# How to avoid pd.read_gbq from accessing wrong email to access big query

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

Getting an error `Reason: 403 POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/id/jobs: Access Denied:` when I trying to connect to big query using `pd.read_gbq`

How can I refer to a particular user account for a particular `project id` in Big query.

Code that I using :

```
import pandas as pd

project_id = "xxxx"
df = pd.read_gbq("select * from table", project_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using `reauth=True` in the `pd.read_gbq` .